# Syntax error while calling a function

Tags: bash, function

So I tried making a function in a script that creates a new variable for each argument when running the script. This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Creating function log
#ARG1=${1}

log() {
  echo "You called DA LOG FUNCTION!!!1!!11one111!"
}

log

#echo "${1}"
#echo "$ARG1"

fcta() {
  for ((x=0;x<1000;++x)); do
   "a$x"=${1}
   if [[ ${#} -gt 1 ]]; then
     shift
   else
     x=1001
   fi
  echo "${a$x}"
#  echo "${1}"
}

fcta $@
```

I get this:

```
vagrant@localhost vagrant]$./luser-demo10.sh 12 12 12
You called DA LOG FUNCTION!!!1!!11one111!
./luser-demo10.sh: line 25: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
./luser-demo10.sh: line 25: `}'
[04:11----------------------------------------
vagrant@localhost vagrant]$
```

So this is line 25

```
#  echo "${1}"
} <----- LINE 25

fcta $@
```

EDIT: Thanks for telling me about the missing "done".
People asked what I was trying to do, well I asked another [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/464085/bash-creating-n-variables-without-assigning-them-one-by-one) for that, since this one has been answered (question was, why did I get a syntax error).
Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your function there is a `do` but no matching `done` to close the command list.

Try [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to verify your scripts. This is a report of detected bugs and suspicious points in your script:

```
Line 16:
  for ((x=0;x<1000;++x)); do
  ^-- SC1009: The mentioned syntax error was in this for loop.
      ^-- SC1073: Couldn't parse this arithmetic for condition. Fix to allow more checks.
                          ^-- SC1061: Couldn't find 'done' for this 'do'.

Line 25:
}
^-- SC1062: Expected 'done' matching previously mentioned 'do'.
 ^-- SC1072: Unexpected keyword/token. Fix any mentioned problems and try again.
```

Answer (score 3):

[andcoz showed what was wrong in your code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/464082/116858) (a missing `done` to close the loop, for starters), but I think it looks as if you *really* want an array.

It's unclear what you want your code to do, but it looks like it's approximately equivalent to copying the command line arguments to an array:

```
a=( "$@" )
```

You can then get a particular element of that array with `${a[i]}` if `i` is a variable with an integer value.

It's crucial to double-quote the expansion of `$@` as this would quote the individual elements of the `$@` list.  Without the double quotes, the shell would split the elements on whitespaces (the contents of `IFS`), and filename generation ("globbing") would be performed on them.

Use `break` to exit a loop instead of setting the loop variable to a value past the end of the loop.