# Creating n variables in Bash without assigning them one by one?

Tags: bash, variable, arguments

How do I create n variables in shell scripts without explicitly assigning them? What I mean is something like a loop that creates `var1`, `var2`, `var3`,...,`varx`, where `x` is a variable I set earlier, something like:

```
read x

for ((a=0;a<x;++a)); do
 variable$a=${RANDOM}
done
```

(Let's ignore the possibility that `x` might be a string for now. But obviously, this doesn't work. How would one do this?

What I actually want to do, is that each argument I wrote in the command line when I executed the script to become it's own variable `ARG1`, `ARG2`... `ARGn` with `${1}`, `${2}`,..., `${n}` as its value, so there will only be as many of these variables, as arguments were set.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to use an array:

```
read x

for (( a=0; a<x; ++a)); do
   variable[a]=$RANDOM
done

printf 'First value is %s\n' "${variable[0]}"

printf 'All values (one by one): %s\n' "${variable[@]}"
printf 'All values (as one string): %s\n' "${variable[*]}"
```

---

For the second part of your question:

```
arg=( "$@" )

printf 'First command line argument: %s\n' "${arg[0]}"
```

Note also that you can easily loop over all command line arguments (or whatever happens to be in `$@`) without storing them anywhere special:

```
for arg do
    printf 'Got command line argument: %s\n' "$arg"
done
```

Comment: But isn't an array just one variable but with multiple values? Would that work for what I'm trying to do? (assign each argument as it's own variable)

Comment: @iamAguest How would you go about using these multiple variables? You would end up with _very_ messy code if you tried to create multiple variables. An array is the proper way to store an indeterminate amount of separate values in any programming language.

Comment: @iamAguest, is there some essential difference? If you would name them `var1`, `var2` etc., you might as well name them `var[1]`, `var[2]` etc. The workarounds for not using arrays are seriously ugly.

Comment: Ah I see, that's really cool, but then, how would I go about doing arithmetic with every value in the array? So something I actually wanted was to have the arguments for the script be all integers, and I would be able to add them all together, something like argtotal=$((arg1+arg2+arg3+...+argn)); echo "$argtotal"

Comment: @iamAguest That particular question has been asked a number of times before.  See e.g. [How do I create a bash script that sums any number of command line arguments?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/98907)

Comment: @iamAguest, see what [BashGuide has to say on Arrays](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays) and [my answer to another related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/413455/170373). It's much _easier_ to loop over an array, than it is to list the similarly-named-but-independent variables (with an array, you don't need to know how many elements it has)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
read x

for ((a=0;a<x;++a)); do
 declare -i variable$a=${RANDOM}
done
```

[declare](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/declareref.html) command permits assigning a value to a variable in the same statement as setting its properties.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `eval` the assignment (but to use an array would be better).

```
#!/bin/bash -vx

read x
for ((a=0;a<x;++a)); do
   eval variable$a=${RANDOM}
done
```

From `man bash`

```
eval [arg ...]
    The args are read and concatenated together into a single command. 
    This command is then read and executed by the shell, and its exit 
    status is returned as the value of eval.
```

Comment: In this case, `$a` must be a number, so it can't contain any extra expansions (which `eval` would process), so you're sort of safe. But really, if you're running in Bash, why would you ever use `eval` instead of an array in a simple case like this? The mess it potentially produces is just too big.

Comment: @ilkkachu I agree that it is a weak solution. But, for example, I used this to initialize some configuration variables, reading a json file (from a remote service) without knowing the needed variable names (to prepare the environment to a legacy software). I remember I needed a lot of checks to avoid word splitting.

Comment: Yeah, _that_ would be different. Though as another answer reminds, even that could be done with `typeset` (or `declare`) instead of `eval`, e.g. `name=foo; value=bar; typeset "$name=$value"; echo $foo` prints `bar`.

Comment: @ilkkachu, except that `declare`/`typeset` also have the side effect of reducing the scope of the variable.

Comment: Note that there is a command injection vulnerability here, the same as in all the other answers, because `$x` is evaluated as an arithmetic expression in `for ((...))`, not because of `eval`. Try for instance `echo 'a[$(uname>&2)0]' | bash -c 'read x; for ((i = 0; i < x; i++)); do : ;done'`. By the way `declare`/`typeset` (even `read` in `bash`) can introduce ACEs the same as `eval` (not here as the content of `$a` is controller). They do also evaluate code.

Answer (score 0):

How about (recent shell needed)

```
 for ((a=0;a<x;++a))
   do  read variable$a <<<${RANDOM}
   done
```